# Nginx metrics "nginx_ingress_controller_requests" shows path as "/" in prometheus

Tags: nginx, prometheus, nginx-ingress

Currently the nginx metrics shows this

`nginx_ingress_controller_requests{container="controller", controller_class="ingress-nginx", controller_namespace="infrastructure", controller_pod="xxxxx-59b68886b9lj9", endpoint="metrics", exported_namespace="xxxxxxxx", exported_service="xxxxx", ingress="xxxxxx", instance="xxxxx", job="xxxxx", method="xxxx", namespace="xxxx", path="/", pod="xxxx", service="xxxxx", status="200"}`
is there  any way I show  request-uri in this path instead of '/'